# Gradient of a radial function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, calculus-of-variations, functional-inequalities

In the lecture on Gagliardo-Niremberg inquality, there was mentioned the fact that for functions:
$$f_{\lambda}(x) = (\lambda + \vert x \vert^q)^\frac{p-n}{p}, \; \text{ where } \frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}=1$$
equality holds.

On checking this, I got stuck on calculating the gradient $\nabla f$. Knowing that $f$ is radially symmetric, is there a property I can use?

Comment: Notice that $\nabla |x| = \frac{x}{|x|}$ and use chain rule.

Comment: This helped! Thank you!